# Updating Json Object using java script based on value

Tags: javascript, json

I have json array named JsonTempArray. And I have mappingId and Name as two fields.[image]

When clicking Male or Female It automatically creates 5 mappingids(1 to 5)
and Name field is Empty.
Like :-

```
JsonTempArray[length]=
 {
   mappingid: Number,//Number has 1 to 5
   Name:""
 }
```

And I have bellow text boxes for each 5 people to fill their name.

[image]

I have below piece code to update Name field

```
for(var len=0;len<JsonTempArray.length;len++)
     {
       if (JsonTempArray[len].Mappingid= mapid ) {
           JsonTempArray[len].Name= document.getElementById('txtName'+len).value;
            }
      }
```

I will pass Particular mappingid while clicking textbox to this.

Eg: Input is:

```
1 John
2 Jack
3 Kin
4 Fin
5 Hol
```

But After updating JsonTempArray has

```
5 Hol
5 Hol
5 Hol
5 Hol
5 Hol
```

Please help me to find how to update each value in loop.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of `mapid` ?

Comment: if i will type value for 1st text box , mapid is 1 ,if 2nd mapid is 2 and so on.

Comment: If possible, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: use == in IF condition instead of =

Comment: i tried with ==. But its javascript so single = is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I should not use for loop in my case.

```
JsonTempArray[id].Name= document.getElementById('txtName'+id);//id is 1/2/3/4/5(mappingid)
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The issues is here instead of checking you where actually assigning:

```
if (JsonTempArray[len].Mappingid= mapid ) {
```

It should be:

```
if (JsonTempArray[len].Mappingid == mapid ) {
```